# I can't call a C# webmethod from json

Tags: c#, json, string, parameters, webmethod

I can't seem to invoke the c# webmethod from javascript. It seems that the problem is    enter code herewith the parameters being transfered to the method.

C# webmethod:

```
//a method that invokes authentication
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Login(string UserName, string Password)
{
    string result = null;
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        TblUser LoginUser = new TblUser();
        bool ans = LoginUser.Login(UserName, Password);
        result = jsonSer.Serialize(ans.ToString());
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = jsonSer.Serialize("noUser");
        return result;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
//a function that grabs username and password
function ClientSideLogin() {
    var UserName = $('#_txtUsername').val();
    var Password = $('#_txtPassword').val();
    Login(UserName, Password);
}
//a function to authenticate from client side    
function Login(_UserName, _Password) {
        // build a datastring in JSON 
        // only a string type should be passed with paranthesis
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
                url: 'WebServices.asmx/Login',   // server side method
                data: '{UserName:' + '"' + _UserName + '"' + ',Password:' + '"' + _Password + '"' + '}',    // the parameters sent to the server
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON', // Choosing a JSON datatype
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
                {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
                        resutls = $.parseJSON(data.d); // parse the answer to json format
                    }
                    else {
                        resutls = $.parseJSON(data);
                    }
                    var resObj = document.getElementById('result');
                    resObj.innerHTML = resutls;
                }, // end of success
                error: function (e) { // handle code in case of error
                    alert("קרתה תקלה בשרת, אנא נסה שוב מאוחר יותר" + e.responseText);
                } // end of error
            }) // end of ajax call
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you have

```
function Login(_UserName, _Password) {
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({ // ...
```

Try changing this to simply

```
function Login(_UserName, _Password) {
    $.ajax({ // ...
```

---

You can't step into the ajax function (that's the async bit of it!) but you can do the following to help you debug:

```
function onSuccess(data) { ... }

...

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: onSuccess,
    ...
});
```

and the same for error. You can then set breakpoints within these functions and they will hit.

Comment: Yes. The C# works. I can't get into the ajax function (it goes into the JQuery function automatically). I'm pretty sure the problem is either with the JQuery version (1.9.1) or the parentheses in the string parameters.

Comment: @user3034124 I've updated the answer with a tip for debugging

Comment: Seems like the problem is with parentheses of the second string.